# How to normalize tag endings using C#

Tags: c#, html, froala

I am using froala wysiwyg editor to generate some content in a Web page.

The problem is that it generates single tags without the normalized ending "/>", for example, IMG tags.

Is there an algorithm to fix that using C#? That  HTML is the input for another component which is expecting a well formed html.

Comment: What exactly does a single tag it generates look like? A proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be handy.

Comment: "Well formed" does not exist for HTML. Maybe it wants well-formed XML such as XHTML?

Comment: @Sach for example, <img src=""> is bad formed. It should be <img src="" />..... Thomas Weller is right..... name is actually XHTML.